# Rails: performing math on a database integer in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a some numbers stored in the database.

```
>> t = Total.first
=> #<Total id: 1, profit: 1058, number: 17, fees: 204, created_at: "2012-01-12 06:44:30", updated_at: "2012-01-12 06:51:13">
```

I want to perform division on one of the integers (an integer that will be updated frequently) and have the division on the newly updated integer. I basically just want to know what percent the profit is of 26,000

```
>> t.profit
=> 1058
>> t.profit / 26000
=> 0
>> t.profit.to_i / 26000
=> 0
```

I was hoping it would be as easy as something like this

```
def index  
  @t = Total.first
  @x = @t.profit / 26000
end
```

View

```
<%= @x %>
```

but it's not working, as the console suggested it wouldn't. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an integer division, so the result is rounded. Convert one of your operands to float.

```
t.profit / 26000.to_f
```

To round that to two decimal places use something like this:

```
"%.2f" % (t.profit / 26000.to_f)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you make it a human readable number. i.e instead of  0.040692307692307694  I want 4%

Comment: O, you wrote your answer to my first comment that i deleted. sorry about that.

Comment: @Michael: There's the code for "0.04". How to turn it to "4%" - that's gonna be your homework :-)

Comment: someone did my homework for me...but to be honest, I did try to get the same solution as him (number_to_percentage) just didn't implement it right.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to Sergio's method is to use Rails' built-in [`number_to_percentage`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_percentage) view helper.

In your controller:

```
def index  
  @t = Total.first
  @x = @t.profit / 260.0  # = 26000 / 100
end
```

In your view:

```
<%= number_to_percentage @x, :precision => 0 %>
```

**Or**, if you're not using `@t` for anything else let the database do the math:

```
def index
  @t = Total.select('profit / 260 AS profit').first
end
```

Then...

```
<%= number_to_percentage @t.profit, :precision => 0 %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I looked at number_to_percentage, trying this number_to_percentage(x) but it didn't work. I'll give yours a shot.

Comment: Your original solution is giving me 0% in the view when it should say 4%

Comment: @x = 0.038461538461538464.  this code gave me .04 <%= number_to_percentage @x, :precision => 2  %>

Comment: Oh, I misread the docs. `number_to_percentage` expects, well, a percent value, e.g. 50 => 50%, not .5 => 50%. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I was sort of thinking the same thing, but I didn't do it right. I put this in the controller @x = @t.profit / 26000.0    and then on the next line   @x = @x x 10.0   but it didn't allow me to multiply

Comment: In Ruby (and most other programming languages) multiplication is done with `*`, not `x`. Anyway, why divide and then multiply when you can just divide by less?